# Alphabetically sorting an ArrayList<String> using .compareTo()

Tags: java, comparator

An assignment we have to do in school is alphabetically sort two different `ArrayList`s into a final arraylist that contains both of the lists elements lexicographically

For example...

`ArrayList sent1` contains in alphabetical order `[., adam, mark]`

`ArrayList sent2` contains in alphabetical order `[., betsy, kyle, william]`

`ArrayList sent3` must contain all of the elements in both ArrayLists in alphabetical order.

I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.  My instructor mentioned using a while loop, but I don't just understand how to code the process.  Combining `sent1` and `sent2` into `sent3` and then using `Collections.sort(sent3)` would make the process so much easier and more compact, but the goal of the lab is to practice the using of `compareTo()`.

Comment: You're not saying the initial lists are sorted, right? You want to combine two unsorted lists and sort them? Your contains statement was kind of confusing

Comment: Check this out - http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/.

Comment: My instructor wrote the code that alphabetized both sent1 and sent2 already.  Now we have to take both of those alphabetized lists and put them alphabetically into sent3.  I am just confused on the how to go about doing it

Comment: Did your instructor give you the code that alphabetized the first two lists?

Comment: Yes sire, but as dumb as I may sound, I am really confused, looking at it, as to how to modify it to put sent1 and sent2 alphabetically into sent3.  I am working on it right now though

Comment: @user3185129 Search for "combining two sorted lists" and stuff like that. Chrylis has a good method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each source list is already sorted, just look at the first element in each list, add the "lower" (alphabetically first) to the output list, and repeat.

Comment: let me give that a whirl.

Comment: So I got that down.  I am using a for() loop and compared sent1.get(i) to sent2.get(i).  If sent1.get(i).compareTo(sent2.get(i) < 0, I add it to sent3.  i get that.  I don't know how to make the loop work so which ever number was greater, it then uses that to compare to the next element

Comment: @user3185129 You need to remove whichever item you insert into the destination list.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple;

```
List<String> sent3 = new ArrayList<String>(sent1);
sent3.addAll(sent2);
Collections.sort(sent3, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.compareTo(b); // usage here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Except this doesn't use `compareTo()`. He even mentioned this option in his question.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ it does internally

Comment: Thank you for the response, however we are not aloud to use Collections.sort().  The goal of the lab is to manually do it using compareTo() ..

Comment: The point is pretty clearly to write client code, not to use the library methods.

Comment: @chrylis how about now?

Comment: @user3185129 I have edited the answer to "use compareTo". Note that you didn't say you couldn't use Collections.sort() in your question. Btw "allowed" is not spelled "aloud" :)

Comment: Better, but having the originals presorted allows a nice merge. Only better scenario would be if the input was a queue.

Comment: Well, not really :) But it's not your fault this time, it's the teacher's. I didn't -1 btw.

Comment: @Bohemian I am a programmer living in the new age of spell check :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to use 2 iterators and just merge these 2 lists.
I'll give you some pseudo code.

```
ArrayList sent1, sent2, sent3;
int i1, i2;
i1 = i2 = 0;
while (i1 < sent1.length() && i2 < sent2.length())
{
 if (sent1[i2].compareTo(sent2[i1])
 {
   sent3.add(sent1[i2]);
   i2++;
 }else
 {
   sent3.add(sent1[i1]);
   i21+;
 }
}
while(i1 < sent1.length()) sent3.add(sent1[i1++]);
while(i2 < sent2.length()) sent3.add(sent2[i2++]);
```

Here each time will add to my sent3 the minimum of the first items in sent1 and sent2. And when I get one of this lists empty, I will just append the rest of other elements into the sent3.

Comment: I have the list in alphabetical order, but the last name, william, is not adding to the list.  I figured out everything else using the for() loop

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do this:

copy array1 and array2 to array3; then, sort array3. you don't know how to sort using compareTo() ? Check is java documentation.